# What does "intent on his impaled insects" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From a passage describing Elizabeth Gaskell's *Mary Barton*,

> The early chapters -- about factory workers walking out in spring into Green Heys Fields, about Alice Wilson, remembering in her cellar the twig-gathering for brooms in the native village that she will never again see, about Job Leigh, **intent on his impaled insects** -- capture the characteristic responses of a generation to the new and crushing experience of industrialism.

I understand the main chapters talk about factory workers, Alice Wilson and Job Leigh, but I don't understand what **"intent on his impaled  insects"** mean.

Translating it as "attentively occupied with pierced insects" doesn't really make much sense to me. What are pierced insects?

Could you please explain?

Comment: I would guess that the guy was an entomologist.

Comment: The question has been answered for you, but can I just point out that it would not have been difficult for you to Find the text on Google Books and search it for 'insects' and discover the answer for yourself. I don't say this to be mean and grumpy, but to try and help you realise how much you can find out with the help fo some widely accessible resources. https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JzqgBYZje-QC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Elizabeth+Gaskell+Mary+Barton,&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_zPDVtKbUAhVoIsAKHXx5B6EQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=Insects&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_collecting):

> **Insect collecting** refers to the collection of insects and other arthropods for scientific study or as a hobby.
>   ...
>   Historically insect collecting has been widespread and was in the Victorian age a very popular educational hobby.
>   ...
>   The usual method of display is in a glass-covered box, with the insects mounted on specially made non corrosive insect pins stuck into suitable foam plastic or paper covered cork at the bottom of the box.

[image]

Image from: [Entomological equipment for mounting and storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomological_equipment_for_mounting_and_storage)

Comment: Here's an [image](http://www.biologyjunction.com/insect7.jpg) of the impalement.